# how to get the smsc number of a phone in android?

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to get the SMS center number of a phone programmatically in android. Is that possible? I have tried searching but found nothing concrete.

Comment: using null in the sms manager function helps. BUT, I want to get the number. Thanks.

Comment: hello can you got the SMSC number? if yes.!!! then please guide me how to get the SMSC number I try several things but can't get this..

Answer (score 3):

Dial this number:
* # * # 4 6 3 6 * # * #
go to phone information and at the bottom you will see the SMSC field, press refresh and there you go

Comment: hi there ...i want to get the SMSC programatically..and not by pressing some keys... :-s.. thanks for the info,though :)

Comment: I will give you some tips on how to do this, this is in theory:
Search for the Apktor en google, this will show you how a program call intents and applications, then use the DDMS while dialing the number above and look at the name of the application that is launched and remember it, the extract that application from the phone and use the Apktor to reverse-engineer it and search for the intent that launch the SMSC

Comment: There's a mistake at the end of your number, it should be `* # * # 4 6 3 6 # * # *`

Answer (score -1):

Use an app called advance signal status. Go to bottom click advanced. Click phone info. Click smsc. Click refresh it gives you number.