# Option to send sms using Sim1 or Sim2 programmatically

Tags: android, sms, sim-card, smsmanager

I have an Android phone with 2 SIM card and I want to send sms using Sim1 or Sim2.By default the message is sent from sim1. But i want to send sms from sim2. Is it possible to setting to send sms using Sim1 or Sim2?

It would be great if there is an setting options to send sms using Sim1 or Sim2.. this is useful for dual SIM android phones.
I created sms application android I've been able to sms application smoothly but default sms sent by SIM 1.But I want to send the sms programmatically by setting to send the sms by sim1 or sim2?

Comment: AFAIK there's no standard way to do this, since the Android SDK does not support dual SIM cards. Hacks involving reflection might work however - there are quite a few similar questions on SO already!

Comment: Hi, Jeba, Have you got solution for this. Please help me if you got

Comment: @GangadharNimbally, Hi Not yet get any solution for this...me too looking for the solution.

Comment: You can find the detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile/30677542

Answer (score 22):

You can use this code for API level 22+ (Android 5.0) `LOLLIPOP_MR1`.

```
private void sendDirectSMS() {

    private static String SENT = "SMS_SENT", DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
        SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    // SEND BroadcastReceiver
    BroadcastReceiver sendSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.sms_sent));
                    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SEND_REMINDER_SMS_APP_SUCCESS);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.sms_send_failed_try_again));
                    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SEND_REMINDER_SMS_APP_FAILED);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_service_sms_failed));
                    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SEND_REMINDER_SMS_APP_FAILED);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_service_sms_failed));
                    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SEND_REMINDER_SMS_APP_FAILED);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_service_sms_failed));
                    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SEND_REMINDER_SMS_APP_FAILED);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    // DELIVERY BroadcastReceiver
    BroadcastReceiver deliverSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.sms_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.sms_not_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(sendSMS, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    registerReceiver(deliverSMS, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    String smsText = getSmsText();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
        if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

            SubscriptionInfo simInfo1 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo2 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(1);

            //SendSMS From SIM One
            SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo1.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(customer.getMobile(), null, smsText, sentPI, deliveredPI);

            //SendSMS From SIM Two
            SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo2.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(customer.getMobile(), null, smsText, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
    } else {
        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(customer.getMobile(), null, smsText, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.sms_sending, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add permission in your `AndoridManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: what SENT & DELIVERED varaiable value?
and what is "customer" in line sendTextMessage(customer.getMobile(),...?

Comment: @asqaI have edited the answer with SENT & DELIVERED value,  customer.getMobile() is mobile number

Comment: I would highly recommend this much cleaner solution (no reflection needed, works for API level 22+)

Comment: showing exception " Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: can not get service which is named 'isms0' not working in devices"

Comment: How should developers save the chosen subscriptionInfo, so that it will be chosen next time the user chooses to send an SMS ? Is there some unique ID there? iccId? The phone number (useful as this is the one that will be sent from) ? If there is no default SIM card chosen for SMS (checked via subscriptionId < 0) , is there an Intent to let the user choose it?

Answer (score 9):

```
SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(int subscriptionId).sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text,PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent);
```

---

this can be working after 5.1 Lollipop version.before that we need to see more. once i got the answer i will update.

Comment: so how to send either from sim1 or sim2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out tasker,  you would be able to user it to build a toggle widget for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full sample, showing how to choose one, and tested on real device (OnePlus 2) with 2 sim cards. Note that you should handle permissions (grant them before using the code) :

**manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />-->
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />-->
```

**build.gradle**

```
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:text="send sms" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.*
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.util.Log
import android.util.LongSparseArray
import android.view.View
import android.view.autofill.AutofillManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.HintRequest
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient
    private val partialSmsIdToSmsReceiverMap = LongSparseArray<SmsBroadcastReceiver>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.visibility = View.GONE
        tryGetCurrentUserPhoneNumber(this)
        googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API).build()
        if (phoneNumberToSendTo.isEmpty()) {
            val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build()
            val intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, hintRequest)
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(intent.intentSender, REQUEST_PHONE_NUMBER, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed to show phone picker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else
            onGotPhoneNumberToSendTo(phoneNumberToSendTo)

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHONE_NUMBER) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val cred: Credential? = data?.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
                phoneNumberToSendTo = cred?.id ?: ""
                if (phoneNumberToSendTo.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(this, "failed to get phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                else
                    onGotPhoneNumberToSendTo(phoneNumberToSendTo)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onGotPhoneNumberToSendTo(normalizedPhoneNumberToSendSmsTo: String) {
        button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        button.text = "send SMS to $normalizedPhoneNumberToSendSmsTo"
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            val messageToSend = "Hello there"
            val parts = smsManager.divideMessage(messageToSend)
            val sentIntents = ArrayList<PendingIntent>(parts.size)
            val fullSmsMessageId = fullSmsIdCounter++
            Log.d("AppLog", " sendSmsMessage sending sms #$fullSmsMessageId parts count:${parts.size} messageToSend:\n$messageToSend")
            val pendingPartialSmsIds = HashSet<Long>()
            for (i in 0 until parts.size) {
                val partialSmsId = partialSmsIdCounter++
                Log.d("AppLog", " sendSmsMessage sending sms #$fullSmsMessageId part id:${partialSmsId}")
                val action = "$ACTION_SMS_SENT_FORMAT$partialSmsId"
                sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, Intent(action), 0))
                val smsSentBroadcastReceiver = SmsBroadcastReceiver(fullSmsMessageId, partialSmsId)
                partialSmsIdToSmsReceiverMap.put(partialSmsId, smsSentBroadcastReceiver)
                applicationContext.registerReceiver(smsSentBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(action))
                pendingPartialSmsIds.add(partialSmsId)
            }
            sendSmsUsingDefaultSimCard(applicationContext, normalizedPhoneNumberToSendSmsTo, parts, sentIntents)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi", "MissingPermission")
    fun sendSmsUsingDefaultSimCard(applicationContext: Context, destinationAddress: String, parts: ArrayList<String>,
                                   sentIntents: ArrayList<PendingIntent>? = null, deliveryIntents: ArrayList<PendingIntent>? = null) {
        val defaultSmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        val phoneNumber = if (destinationAddress.startsWith("+")) destinationAddress else "+$destinationAddress"
        //check if we have multi-SIM and don't have a default one to work with, so that we will choose it ourselves
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            defaultSmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
            return
        }
        val subscriptionManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
        val defaultSubscriptionId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId()
        val smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(defaultSubscriptionId)
        if (smsManager != null) {
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
            return
        }
        val activeSubscriptionInfoList: MutableList<SubscriptionInfo>? = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
        val subscriptionInfoId = activeSubscriptionInfoList?.getOrNull(0)?.subscriptionId
        if (subscriptionInfoId != null)
            SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfoId).sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
        else
            defaultSmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
    }

    private inner class SmsBroadcastReceiver(val fullSmsId: Long, val partialSmsId: Long) : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(someContext: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d("AppLog", " SmsBroadcastReceiver onReceive")
            applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this)
            partialSmsIdToSmsReceiverMap.remove(partialSmsId)
            val smsError: String? = when (resultCode) {
                -1, 0 /*SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NONE*/ -> null
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE -> "RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF -> "RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU -> "RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE -> "RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED -> "RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NOT_ALLOWED -> "RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NOT_ALLOWED"
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NEVER_ALLOWED -> "RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NEVER_ALLOWED"
                /**SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_FDN_CHECK_FAILURE*/
                6 -> "RESULT_ERROR_FDN_CHECK_FAILURE"
//                16 /*SmsManager.RESULT_MODEM_ERROR*/ -> "RESULT_MODEM_ERROR"
//                111 /*SmsManager.RESULT_RIL_MODEM_ERR*/ -> "RESULT_RIL_MODEM_ERR"
                else -> "Unknown error"
            }
            Log.d("AppLog", "SmsBroadcastReceiver sms #$fullSmsId part #$partialSmsId send-state updated. sent fine?${smsError == null} (error:$smsError) errorCode:$resultCode")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_PHONE_NUMBER = 1
        private var partialSmsIdCounter = 0L
        private var fullSmsIdCounter = 0L
        private const val ACTION_SMS_SENT_FORMAT = "_ACTION_SENT_"
        private var phoneNumberToSendTo = ""

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "HardwareIds")
        private fun tryGetCurrentUserPhoneNumber(context: Context): String {
            if (phoneNumberToSendTo.isNotEmpty())
                return phoneNumberToSendTo
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val subscriptionManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
                try {
                    subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList?.forEach {
                        val number: String? = it.number
                        if (!number.isNullOrBlank()) {
                            phoneNumberToSendTo = number
                            return number
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                }
            }
            try {
                val telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
                val number = telephonyManager.line1Number ?: ""
                if (!number.isBlank()) {
                    phoneNumberToSendTo = number
                    return number
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION WITHOUT android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        SubscriptionManager subs = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        if (subs != null) {
            Log.d("sim_spalsh", "num sims = " + subs.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax());

            if (subs.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax() > 1) {

                //SendSMS From SIM One
                SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(0)
                        .sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "sim1", null, null);

                //SendSMS From SIM Two
                SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(1)
                        .sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "sim2", null, null);

            }
        }
    }
```

Your have to guarantee the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Comment: Is there a solution to get it before Android API 22 ? Also, do apps that try to send SMS the normal way (using sendMultipartTextMessage) crash in case there is more than 1 sim card?

Answer (score -4):

The option is available in Android Settings- navigate to Settings>>Wireless & Networks>>SIM Management>>Default Settings>>Messages>> and select 'Always Ask".