# How can send sms in android in dual SIM?

Tags: java, android, sms, message, android-broadcast

How can send sms in android with dual sim for broadcast not intent?? How can detect dual sim in android? User wants to select sim for send sms broadcast. In android set the default sim for sending msg in dual sim in android.

Thanks,

Nitin

Comment: Hay, Have you got the solution to send SMS with particular SIM. Please share here, If you know. Thank you

Comment: Try my code.. I have solved this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677542/2267723 .. good luck

Answer (score 5):

refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/2771869

You can use Java reflection to get both IMEI numbers.

Using these IMEI numbers you can check weather phone is DUAL SIM or not.

Try following activity :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

        String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1();
        String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2();

        boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
        boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

        boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(" IME1 : " + imeiSIM1 + "\n" +
                " IME2 : " + imeiSIM2 + "\n" +
                " IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + "\n" +
                " IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + "\n" +
                " IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + "\n");
    }
}
```

And here is TelephonyInfo.java :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public final class TelephonyInfo {

    private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
    private String imeiSIM1;
    private String imeiSIM2;
    private boolean isSIM1Ready;
    private boolean isSIM2Ready;

    public String getImeiSIM1() {
        return imeiSIM1;
    }

    /*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
        TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
    }*/

    public String getImeiSIM2() {
        return imeiSIM2;
    }

    /*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
        TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
        return isSIM1Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
        return isSIM2Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isDualSIM() {
        return imeiSIM2 != null;
    }

    private TelephonyInfo() {
    }

    public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

        if(telephonyInfo == null) {

            telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return telephonyInfo;
    }

    private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        String imei = null;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                imei = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return imei;
    }

    private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        boolean isReady = false;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                    isReady = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return isReady;
    }


    private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

        public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
            super(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit :

Getting access of methods like "getDeviceIdGemini" for other SIM slot's detail has prediction that method exist.

If that method's name doesn't match with one given by device manufacturer than it will not work. You have to find corresponding method name for those devices.

Finding method names for other manufacturers can be done using Java reflection as follows :

```
public static void printTelephonyManagerMethodNamesForThisDevice(Context context) {

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    try {
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method[] methods = telephonyClass.getMethods();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < methods.length; idx++) {

            System.out.println("\n" + methods[idx] + " declared by " + methods[idx].getDeclaringClass());
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT :

As Seetha pointed out in her comment :

```
telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdDs", 0);
telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdDs", 1);
```

It is working for her. She was successful in getting two IMEI numbers for both the SIM in Samsung Duos device.

Comment: @mohammand rababah The answer for detect dual sim. But how to send sms by particular sim

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for API level 22+, needs no reflection. It is based on the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380282/3427883.

Basically to detect if you have two sim cards or more, you need to check this condition

```
SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
            if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
//do you stuff here
}
```

Then based on the user selection the sim card slot (0, 1, ...), you can send the SMS on the selected sim card. Below is a method that does this

```
public static boolean sendSMS(Context context, int simID, String toNum, String centerNum, String smsText, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent) {
    SmsManager smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();
    int[] param;
    Method method = null;
    try {
        SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
        if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(simID);
            SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(toNum, null, smsText, null, null);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsSimUtil.sendSMS", "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Don't forget to add these permission in your app AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() is returning 0 for me. Can't figure out what is causing that. Do you have any advice?